# How to achieve this effect in shading?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I was working on implementing a gradient texture with a noise texture, but only wanting the noise texture to effect a certain masked out area, I don't want noise texture effect in the top or bottom of from the border, I want them to be gradients, but just on that edge I want the noise/distortion effect, I have current node setup:

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I also want to be able to individually control the gradients, ie have two different colors if I wanted for the top and bottom half

Comment: in my opinion, you should accept the answer that is provided by Robin. Editing your question adding details is not fair at all (again: in my opinion).

Comment: right I realized that I should have clarified in the beginning, I have upvoted the answer and I'm hoping hopefully if Robin see's it again he can modify and tell me how to achieve my desired effect, if there is no response by tomorrow I will accept his answer as this is pretty similar to what I wanted anyways :)

Answer (score 4):

As I understand your question, you want the *Noise* to be masked..

Here's one way. In this case, I found it easier to use Object-Space for the texture coordinates, putting 0 at the center without further adustment. But you could compensate, in some other space...

[image]

To conceal any boundary between the noise and the plain background the last stop in its mapping was drag-drop copied from the background color.

This shows mask, noise, and masked-noise :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, I want to be able to individually control the color for the top and bottom half of the gradient, in the shader you mentioned, I seem to only be able to control both, is there a way I can control them separately?

Comment: well, this is kind of after sale services... question edited... : (

Comment: @lemon wdym, confused about sale services haha?

Comment: @NunMatters Ahem.... (  * resisting temptation to wag finger  *)  .. Do  you want the color to show through your dark noise, or do you want the noise to be black-and-white, _as in your original question_ ? Or do you want a noisy transition between colors, with no black or white? Or.. something else altogether ... maybe ?  I mean... who knows, eh?  :)

Comment: so basically I want like a gradient from dark to white on the top half before the noise edge, then the same type of gradient but a different color for the bottom half, I do also want to be able to have a different color for the noise, my end goal is to use all of this in a shader, so noisy will be a shader, same with the gradients as well, the .blend file is pretty close to what I want, but I want to be able to individually change colors for the top and bottom, so if I wanted top to be red and bottom half to be blue, the noise on ur .blend file does allow me to have a color so that is ok

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks again btw! srry for not being too clear haha

Comment: @NunMatters late, here, will get to another guess at it tomorrow .. :)

Comment: Sure! will be looking forward to it, I have asked countless discord servers w/ no help so this is my only hope here haha

Comment: @NunMatters  .. and I've had to be AFK today.. sorry

Comment: @NunMatters  It's still actually  tricky to figure out exactly what you need.. there are so many variations possible. Here's a start at a group that makes a noisy transition down Y between 2 colors, disguising the boundaries between pure color and noise-mix:  https://blend-exchange.com/b/Or2YJv0X/